# How would I enhance this dimly lit picture?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

My friend took this photograph of me at a resort. However, as it was night and dimly lit the picture is not pleasing (Thanks to my friend's lack of pro photography skills) !

I downloaded GIMP in order to enhance the picture and try to make it better but sadly I'm a newbie to photo editing and all the tools in GIMP have confused me. How could I improve this image?

[image]
Thank You

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I've edited your question because asking for free work is not really allowed here. So, I've made it more of a "how to do it" question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure anyone could provide you a full tutorial on how to rescue over-dark & wrongly-lit photographs. This one suffers from both those issues & also a third… it's not of high-enough technical quality to rescue.
It's too noisy. If you try to lift the dark areas, there's not enough detail in them.

For a beginner, this type of rescue operation is often best performed by a dedicated HDR app, such as Aurora HDR. It will attempt to lift the dark areas without killing the bright areas… however, in this case there's not a lot that it can do to fix this shot.
Here's a two-minute attempt, to show you how little detail can be regained.

The only way to have fixed this shot would have been to not have almost **all** the lighting behind the subject.

[image]

Following Billy Kerr's answer using Gimp itself, here's an alternative method using Curves. It's similar to using the Shadows/Highlights feature, but allows for finer control. The same caveats apply, the image is too dark & too noisy to fully rescue by this or any method.
Here I've over-pushed the settings to make the result clearer to see…

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The photo is quite poor quality, and so editing it will probably produce poor quality results. Nothing you can really do about that unfortunately, but you could improve it a little.

In GIMP do *Colours > Shadows-Highlights*, and move the sliders to lighten the shadows. Don't go too far with this or it will just look bad. The problem here is that the image is quite noisy, so if you brighten too much it will make the problem worse.

Anyway, here's an Example showing the adjustments

[image]

Before and after

[image]

Since you're new to GIMP you'll also need to know how to save it. Do *File > Export As*, and choose a new file name, and set the file type to PNG.

Comment: Brave attempt (as always) I'd looked at curves & given up on the idea;)

Comment: @Tetsujin there are also Tone Mapping (HDR-like) filters in GIMP which could be used for an effect similar to your answer.  These are under Colours > Tone Mapping, but they're a little tricky to use. I suggested this method because the OP is a beginner, and it's fairly easy.

Comment: I added a Curves example to mine, so at least I'm showing some kind of solution using Gimp itself. The Tone Mapping dialog on Mac seems too buggy to actually use (beachballing with an almost unused CPU on a 12-core Mac Pro) - I just grabbed the (almost) latest 2.10 so I'm fumbling around even more than usual. I've lived in Photoshop too long ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Here's [an example](https://imgur.com/a/kYJJQYE) using the Reinhard 2005 Tone Mapping filter. You have to be patient when using these filters as they are a little CPU intensive, not so much buggy, just sluggish.

Comment: Indeed. Might be interesting to try it on a full-res image sometime, but even on this little jpg I see it hit 100% of one core for a few seconds, so it looks like it's single-threaded & means it can't even update the GUI whilst it's thinking, while 23 other HT cores sit waiting ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - GIMP doesn't seem to take advantage of multiple cores like Photoshop does, even though it does have multiple threading. This may be a deliberate policy of the GIMP devs, since GIMP can work (albeit slowly) on just about any old computer, unlike recent versions of Photoshop.

Comment: I trashed 2.10 & clean installed 2.8 to see if it behaved any better - it didn't, though on 2.10 I have half the interface messed up (UI fonts missing) though I do prefer the newer interface. I think I shall lay it down carefully & sidle slowly back over towards Photoshop for now ;) I'd still recommend Aurora HDR (or indeed Luminar) for any enthusiastic amateur. Not free, but nowhere near Adobe prices & really easy to just play with to see if you find something interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116997/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-tetsujin).

Answer (score 1):

Lights are in a little wrong places, but the photo shooting session is already done, so only edits are possible.

Duplicate the image layer. Apply to the copy Color > Curves to lift the person a little more visible. Do not get disturbed by lights which become bloomy and the dark background which start to look noisy:

[image]

Insert a black layer mask to the adjusted top layer. Black means full transparency, so the edited layer is hidden. Bring the person back by painting white to the layer mask with a big soft brush.

[image]

You can fix an error by painting black or by pressing Ctrl+Z, but there's no need to get the white to cover exactly and only the person. In professional photo sessions the lights often cover also a more or less the background and the target has shadow areas.

This is a 2 layer image. It must be exported to get a JPG or PNG.

Comment: +1 for another nice answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1 is fixing colors so that the areas which are too dark are easier to see. You can do that with Levels, Curves and similar tools, whichever you prefer.

However, step #2 is cleaning up all the noise from low ISO and I don't think GIMP (or Photoshop) has the necessary tools. I usually use Topaz Denoise AI for this as it has a lot of flexibility and can improve sharpness too.

This is what I got:

[image]

If you don't have access to Topaz applications, you can also try various [free denoising neural models for ESRGAN](https://upscale.wiki/wiki/Model_Database#Noise) like 1x_ISO_denoise_v2.